# How do I consume and print a Promise result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, ethers.js

I'm trying to get the current block number from Binance Smart Chain (BSC).
In the [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getNetwork), provider.getBlockNumber() returns a Promise object.

Here are my attempts to consume and print the current block number into console.
I'm using Node.js v16.5.0 and Ethers.js 5.4.1.

```js
var ethers = require("ethers");
var url = "wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443";
    
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(url);

const blockNumber = async function() {
    return await provider.getBlockNumber();
}

console.log(blockNumber());
process.exit();
```

This returns `Promise { <pending> }` on the console.

This block of code:

```js
var ethers = require("ethers");
var url = "wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443";

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(url);

async function blockNumber() {
    const blockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
    return blockNumber();
}

blockNumber().then(data => {console.log(data)});
process.exit();
```

output exactly nothing in the console, almost as there's nothing wrong in the code.

Expected output should be a number, like 9380976.

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT 1: Added `process.exit()` because that's supposed to be in the original post.

ANSWER by @purple:

```js
var ethers = require("ethers");
var url = "wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443";

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(url);

async function blockNumber() {
    const blockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
    return blockNumber;
}

blockNumber().then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    process.exit();
});
```

Result:

```bash
> node app
*pauses for a bit, then prints*
9397167
>
```

Comment: You use `.then()` or `await` to get the value out of a promise.  This is still true for the return value of any `async` function because an `async` function ALWAYS returns a promise.  FYI, `return await provider.getBlockNumber();` offers you nothing useful over `return provider.getBlockNumber();`.  A promise is still returned from the `async` function either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `return blockNumber;` instead of `return blockNumber();`?